# Videos stuck at first frame

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, codec, flash-player

I got a new laptop a few weeks ago (Dell XPS 15). Soon after I installed the basic software I needed (Browser, Antivirus, E-Mail software, ...) , videos started to get stuck at the first frame. Audio does also not play. Netflix, Youtube, and even .mp4 files on the HDD are affected. Flash Player, Shockwave Player and Browser are on the newest version. I also re-installed each a few times but it didn't change anything.

I also noticed that the system boots relatively slow and is very slow for the first ~3-4 minutes after boot.

Most of the time a simple reboot solves the problem. But it is very annoying. What could be the reason? I think it is not a HTML5-Player / Flash-Player problem because .mp4 files also don't work.

Here's what *MediaInfo* prints for a sample .mp4 file:

```
General
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                    : mp42 (mp42/avc1)
File size                   : 5.26 MiB
Duration                    : 1 min
Overall bit rate            : 734 kb/s
Encoded date                : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:39
Tagged date                 : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:40

Video
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : Baseline@L3
Format settings, CABAC      : No
Format settings, ReFrames   : 2 frames
Format settings, GOP        : M=1, N=64
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 1 min
Duration_LastFrame          : 95 ms
Bit rate                    : 613 kb/s
Width                       : 640 pixels
Height                      : 360 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 24.000 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.111
Stream size                 : 4.39 MiB (83%)
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:39
Tagged date                 : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:40
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.601

Audio
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AAC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile              : LC
Codec ID                    : 40
Duration                    : 1 min
Source duration             : 1 min
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 64.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel positions           : Front: L R
Sampling rate               : 22.05 kHz
Frame rate                  : 21.533 FPS (1024 spf)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 478 KiB (9%)
Source stream size          : 478 KiB (9%)
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:39
Tagged date                 : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:40

Other #1
ID                          : 3
Type                        : Hint
Format                      : RTP
Codec ID                    : rtp 
Duration                    : 1 min
Title                       : Hinted Video Track
Language                    : English
Default                     : No
Encoded date                : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:39
Tagged date                 : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:40
Duration_LastFrame          : 95

Other #2
ID                          : 4
Type                        : Hint
Format                      : RTP
Codec ID                    : rtp 
Duration                    : 1 min
Title                       : Hinted Sound Track
Language                    : English
Default                     : No
Encoded date                : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:39
Tagged date                 : UTC 2010-02-09 01:55:40
Source duration             : 60140
Source_Duration_FirstFrame  : 46
Source frame count          : 648
Source stream size          : 41456
Stream size                 : 41456
Bit rate mode               : VBR
```

I am running Windows 10 64-Bit.

Comment: It might be bad codecs. Try to install the [K-Lite Mega Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_mega_codec_pack.htm) and reboot. If this doesn't help, try another player such as VLC. Some details about which players are getting stuck will help.

Answer (score 1):

It might be bad codecs.

Try to install the [K-Lite Mega Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_mega_codec_pack.htm) and reboot. If this doesn't help, try another player such as VLC.

Some details about which players are getting stuck and for what kind of video will help.

Comment: I installed the Codec Pack but it didn't work. What I noticed is just that it works on every 2nd boot. If I turn of my PC over night and boot it the next morning it doesn't work.If I then directly reboot it, it works. Every kind of video is affected.

Comment: Weird. Try general troubleshooting : [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html). See if you have any other codec pack or video product and uninstall those you don't need after installing K-Lite. Questions: (1) Did the K-Lite installation give errors about badly-installed codecs? (2) Does [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) also get stuck?

Comment: No, K-Lite did not give any errors. I will install VLC now and try it tomorrow morning. I am running sfc now, it will take some time.

Comment: sfc finished and did not find any errors. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Waiting for info regarding VLC.

Comment: VLC also does not work .Error: "Starting the server failed".

Comment: Are you sure the text of the VLC error is exactly as above? K-Lite has installed the Mediainfo tool - open such a file and post the information, specially Format & Codec info. Go to [XPS 15 Product Support](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/drivers/advanced?rvps=y), section Guide Me, and check for drivers. In Windows Settings, click Update & Security and install if updates are available.

Comment: I have already installed all Windows updates and Dell updates. I am sure the error is exactly as above, I just translated it into english. What excatly do you mean with _open such a file and post the information, specially Format & Codec info_?

Comment: Start Mediainfo, click where indicated, navigate to the file and OK. You can select and copy the displayed info.

Comment: I edited my original post and added the information.

Comment: Curious. I see this is a short video - could you post it somewhere so I could have a look?

Comment: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html It is the mp4 version of "Big Bunny Buck"

Comment: I don't have any problem playing it, having K-Lite Mega installed. Try to [boot in Safe mode](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10), and see if the problem arrives (that is if it is playable at all in this mode). If it works fine or sort-of, then some installed product is responsible for the problem.

Comment: Well, thank you for your help so far. I think I will completly reinstall the OS.

Comment: Although we will never know what the problem was, this will most probably solve it. While installing products in the fresh OS, check video play from time to time, just in case one of them is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're using preinstalled operating system. I know that many people won't agree with me, but after working few years in IT support I learned this: reinstalling with **clean OS** (without vendor additives) is **often** much quicker solution than trying to understand "what went wrong" and fixing it. Especially when you're using preinstalled operating system with additional software from vendor. If you need any software, which was included by Dell, everything is available on their [support website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/pl/pl/plbsdt1/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/drivers).

This also refers to OS that was installed by user. Many things could went wrong in the installation process, so if you see thing that shouldn't happen in good-working OS - you should think about reinstalling it. Trying to fix some problems may cause another problems in long-term usage.

But... If you just have (need) to fix this...
You mentioned that you have problems with YouTube, Netflix but also with .mp4 in your local files. You should:

1. Check `Programs and Features` in `Control Panel` for software somehow connected to video files. It may be some enhancer, codec or something like this. If you find it - uninstall it.
2. Download newest [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/) ("full" bundle is enough) and install it.

If problem won't disappear, try to check "Task Manager" for process that may cause this and try to "kill" it.